# Where does the ohr hachaim say that one who fails to destroy avoda zara is also oveir on the lav of not serving it?

Tags: sources-mekorot, avodah-zarah

The ohr hachaim is quoted as saying that one who fails to destroy avoda zara is also oveir on the lav of not serving it in "hatekufah hagedolah" (r' menachem mendel kasher) in perek 13 "(ד' ר"ש)" according to mekoros sheet i saw it quoted in. Where does he say this? I searched hatekufah hagedolah on hebrew books and wasn't able to find (in first two volumes at least - all they have, maybe there are more)

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for הזורק אבן למרכוליס זוהי עבודתו, הפוער עצמו לבעל פעור זוהי עבודתו mishna Sanhedrin 7/6